# R referring to elements of a vector in a list of vectors

Tags: r, list

If I have a list with e.g. coordinates in it, how can I refer to the elements of each element of the list individually?

`coord=list(c(104,1.5),c(144.97,-37.78),c(121.5,25.03))`

What I'd like to do is something like

```
for(i in coord){
print(i[1])
print(i[2])}
```

The above example doesn't work
(In practice of course I'll use them to plot something).

The following one does work but I'm trying to see if there is a more elegant 'R' way to do it.

```
coord=c(c(104,1.5),c(144.97,-37.78),c(121.5,25.03))
for(i in seq(1,length(coord),2)){
print(coord[i])
print(coord[i+1])
}
```

Comment: Your two definitions of `coord` result in (a) a list of three elements and (b) a vector of 6 elements.

Comment: Why the first doesn't work?

Comment: hi @mnel, that's right. I'm looking for a simple way to get the x and y coords for example from each element of the first example.

Comment: What is wrong with for(i in coord){print(i)}

Comment: hi @mnel I need to get at the underlying elements (e.g. 104 and 1.5) separately. So a better example might be wanting to `points(x=i[1],y=i[2],pch=1)` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get what exactly do you want...

aren't you trying to do this?

```
> coord[[1]][1]
[1] 104
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need `unlist` for that.

```
unlist(coord)
## [1] 104.00   1.50 144.97 -37.78 121.50  25.03
```

If you are looking to extract them as 2 column data to plot then you should cast `unlist`ed data to `matrix`

```
plot(matrix(unlist(coord), ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE))
```

This should give you figure as below

[image]

Comment: thanks @geektrader, `unlist(i[1])[1]` is definitely a solution, but it feels a little roundabout. I'll mark this up if something more elegant isn't forthcoming.